# How can I show limted products in category like I want 8 products

Tags: magento-1.9

**I am using this code, can anyone help me out with this:**

> {{block type="catalog/product_list" limit="8" column_count="4"
>   category_id="1" template="catalog/products.phtml"}}

Comment: Can You post the block file to related template file @Touseef Akhtar

Comment: The block is working but i wanted to show limited products like 4,8,12 etc

Comment: the collection limit is written in block it self can You just post Your Block file @Touseef Akhtar

Comment: `<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col">
      `

Comment: Some start code.

Comment: Don't know how to send i am new here.

Comment: Paste whole Your block code in Question above update @Touseef Akhtar

Comment: i copy past its too long showing error comment box area.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" product_count="12" column_count="4" category_id="1" template="catalog/products.phtml"}}
```

Comment: `{{block type="catalog/product_list" product_count="12" column_count="4" category_id="1" template="catalog/products.phtml"}}`

not working